# Cоставьте быструю рекурсивную функцию вычислений чисел Фибоначчи, воспользовавшись векторно-матричным представлением

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, числа-фибоначчи

Ошибка не удалось запустить программу. Помогите исправить ошибку.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int counter = 0;


struct Matrix2x2 {
    int _11, _12, _21, _22;

     Matrix2x2& operator*=(const Matrix2x2 matrix)
    {
        int new11(matrix._11*_11 + matrix._21*_12);
        int new12(matrix._12*_11 + matrix._22*_12);
        int new21(matrix._11*_21 + matrix._21*_22);
        int new22(matrix._12*_21 + matrix._22*_22);

        _11 = new11;
        _12 = new12;
        _21 = new21;
        _22 = new22;

        return;
    }
};

void powerFib(Matrix2x2 &res, Matrix2x2 &m, int &n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 1)
        {
            res *= m;
            --n;
        }
        else
        {
            m *= m;
            n /= 2;
        }
        counter++;
        powerFib(res, m, n);
    }
}


int fastRecursiveFib(int n)
{
    Matrix2x2 res =
    {
        1, 0,
        0, 1
    };

    Matrix2x2 m =
    {
        1, 1,
        1, 0
    };

    double f0 = 0, f1 = 1;
    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        return f0; break;
    case 1:
        return f1; break;
    default:
        counter++;
        powerFib(res, m, n);

        return res._21;
    }
}

void zet(double &y, double &x, unsigned int &k)
{
    if (k > 0)
    {
        if (k % 2 == 1)
        {
            y *= x; k--;
        }
        else
        {
            x *= x; k /= 2;
        };
        counter++;
        zet(y, x, k);
    }
}
double power(double x, unsigned int n)
{
    double y = 1;
    counter++;
    zet(y, x, n);
    return y;
}

void fib(double &f1, double &f2, unsigned int n)
{
    if (n >= 2)
    {
        double f = f2; f2 += f1; f1 = f;
        counter++;
        fib(f1, f2, n - 1);
    }
};
double Fibonaci(unsigned int n)
{
    double f0 = 0, f1 = 1;
    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        return f0; break;
    case 1:
        return f1; break;
    default:
        counter++;
        fib(f0, f1, n);
        return f1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // task 1
    cout << "Power function tests: " << endl;
    double x = 2;
    unsigned int n = 5;

    cout << "2^5 = " << power(x, n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'zet' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;
    // 3^10
    x = 3;
    n = 10;

    cout << "3^10 = " << power(x, n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'zet' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;
    // 100^0
    x = 100;
    n = 0;

    cout << "100^0 = " << power(x, n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'zet' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;
    // -5^7
    x = -5;
    n = 7;

    cout << "-5^7 = " << power(x, n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'zet' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;

    getch();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Fibonacci tests: " << endl;

    n = 5;

    cout << "F(" << n << "): " << Fibonaci(n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'fib' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;

    n = 15;

    cout << "F(" << n << "): " << Fibonaci(n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'fib' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;

    n = 25;

    cout << "F(" << n << "): " << Fibonaci(n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'fib' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;

    getch();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Fast recursive Fibonacci function test: " << endl;

    int next = 1;
    int test = 0;

    while (next == 1)
    {
        cout << "Input non-negative 'n' to compute F(n): " << endl;
        cin >> test;
        while (test < 0)
        {
            cout << "Input valid 'n': " << endl;
            cin >> test;
        }
        cout << "F(" << test << "): " << fastRecursiveFib(test) << endl;
        cout << "Number of calls of 'powerFib' function: " << counter << endl;
        counter = 0;

        cout << "To continue press 1" << endl;
        cin >> next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Ошибка не удалось запустить программу.“ - это вам коммилятор так и сказал?

Answer (score 0):

Откровенно говоря, понять, что нужно и как это у вас реализовано, мне слишком трудно. Но, судя по всему, нужно считать числа Фибоначчи по формуле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда, основываясь на вашем представлении матрицы 2x2, я бы просто [делал так](https://ideone.com/3CK5vD):

```
struct Matrix
{
    int m[2][2] = {{1,1},{1,0}};
};

Matrix operator*(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b)
{
    Matrix m;
    m.m[0][0] = a.m[0][0]*b.m[0][0]+a.m[0][1]*b.m[1][0];
    m.m[0][1] = a.m[0][0]*b.m[0][1]+a.m[0][1]*b.m[1][1];
    m.m[1][0] = a.m[1][0]*b.m[0][0]+a.m[1][1]*b.m[1][0];
    m.m[1][1] = a.m[1][0]*b.m[0][1]+a.m[1][1]*b.m[1][1];
    return m;
}

Matrix pow(Matrix M, int N)
{
    if (N == 1) return Matrix{};
    Matrix m = pow(M,N/2);
    m = m*m;
    if (N%2) m = M*m;
    return m;
}

int fib(int N)
{
    Matrix M = pow(Matrix{},N);
    return M.m[0][1];
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << i << "   " << fib(i) << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не было возвращаемого значения в перегруженном операторе *=
Так собирается и запускается:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;

    int counter = 0;


struct Matrix2x2 {
    int _11, _12, _21, _22;

    Matrix2x2& operator*=(Matrix2x2 matrix)
    {
        int new11(matrix._11*_11 + matrix._21*_12);
        int new12(matrix._12*_11 + matrix._22*_12);
        int new21(matrix._11*_21 + matrix._21*_22);
        int new22(matrix._12*_21 + matrix._22*_22);

        _11 = new11;
        _12 = new12;
        _21 = new21;
        _22 = new22;

        return matrix;
    }
};

void powerFib(Matrix2x2 &res, Matrix2x2 &m, int &n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 1)
        {
            res *= m;
            --n;
        }
        else
        {
            m *= m;
            n /= 2;
        }
        counter++;
        powerFib(res, m, n);
    }
}


int fastRecursiveFib(int n)
{
    Matrix2x2 res =
    {
        1, 0,
        0, 1
    };

    Matrix2x2 m =
    {
        1, 1,
        1, 0
    };

    double f0 = 0, f1 = 1;
    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        return f0; break;
    case 1:
        return f1; break;
    default:
        counter++;
        powerFib(res, m, n);

        return res._21;
    }
}

void zet(double &y, double &x, unsigned int &k)
{
    if (k > 0)
    {
        if (k % 2 == 1)
        {
            y *= x; k--;
        }
        else
        {
            x *= x; k /= 2;
        };
        counter++;
        zet(y, x, k);
    }
}
double power(double x, unsigned int n)
{
    double y = 1;
    counter++;
    zet(y, x, n);
    return y;
}

void fib(double &f1, double &f2, unsigned int n)
{
    if (n >= 2)
    {
        double f = f2; f2 += f1; f1 = f;
        counter++;
        fib(f1, f2, n - 1);
    }
};
double Fibonaci(unsigned int n)
{
    double f0 = 0, f1 = 1;
    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        return f0; break;
    case 1:
        return f1; break;
    default:
        counter++;
        fib(f0, f1, n);
        return f1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // task 1
    cout << "Power function tests: " << endl;
    double x = 2;
    unsigned int n = 5;

    cout << "2^5 = " << power(x, n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'zet' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;
    // 3^10
    x = 3;
    n = 10;

    cout << "3^10 = " << power(x, n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'zet' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;
    // 100^0
    x = 100;
    n = 0;

    cout << "100^0 = " << power(x, n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'zet' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;
    // -5^7
    x = -5;
    n = 7;

    cout << "-5^7 = " << power(x, n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'zet' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;

    getch();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Fibonacci tests: " << endl;

    n = 5;

    cout << "F(" << n << "): " << Fibonaci(n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'fib' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;

    n = 15;

    cout << "F(" << n << "): " << Fibonaci(n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'fib' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;

    n = 25;

    cout << "F(" << n << "): " << Fibonaci(n) << endl;
    cout << "Number of calls of 'fib' function: " << counter << endl;
    counter = 0;

    getch();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Fast recursive Fibonacci function test: " << endl;

    int next = 1;
    int test = 0;

    while (next == 1)
    {
        cout << "Input non-negative 'n' to compute F(n): " << endl;
        cin >> test;
        while (test < 0)
        {
            cout << "Input valid 'n': " << endl;
            cin >> test;
        }
        cout << "F(" << test << "): " << fastRecursiveFib(test) << endl;
        cout << "Number of calls of 'powerFib' function: " << counter << endl;
        counter = 0;

        cout << "To continue press 1" << endl;
        cin >> next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```